# Two successive Pipes

Tags: shell, awk, pipe

Is there an issue with this command line :

```
Foo | awk '/Value1/{printf("%s,",$2)} /Value2/{printf("%s\n",$6)}' | awk '(NR % 5 == 1){print $0}'
```

where `Foo` is a custom program. This command used to work fine. However, since a recent update of a custom distribution (Yocto based). It seems that It doesn't work anymore. Strangely the `awk '(NR % 5 == 1){print $0}'` is not executed and the whole command doesn't display anything ...

Any idea please ?  Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: does the first awk output more than 5 rows?

Comment: make sure you have 'Value1' or 'Value2' for the output of `Foo`

Comment: Well, the first AWK outputs a continuous stream as expected. Actually, even this simple command doesnt work :     `Foo | awk '/Value1/{printf("%s,",$2)} /Value2/{printf("%s\n",$6)}' | awk '{print $0}'`

Comment: @JDoe What shell are you using? Does `Foo | awk '/Value1/{printf("%s,",$2)} /Value2/{printf("%s\n",$6)}' > tmp && awk '{print $0}' < tmp` work? How about `Foo | awk '/Value1/{printf("%s,",$2)} /Value2/{printf("%s\n",$6)}' > >(awk '{print $0}')`?

Comment: Very good suggestion ! The first command : `Foo | awk '/Value1/{printf("%s,",$2)} /Value2/{printf("%s\n",$6)}` > tmp && awk '{print $0}' < tmp' produces nothing (a blinking prompt) .... I have the same result as the one produced with two pipes.              

Concerning the second command, it produces a error ...

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Well, the same command used to work  with my previous distribution. I moved to a home made one based on Yocto project. To answer to your questions sequentially : 1) `Foo | awk '/Value1/{printf("%s,",$2)} /Value2/{printf("%s\n",$6)}'`
1496237500440,0
1496237500467,0
1496237500567,0
1496237500667,0
1496237500767,0
1496237500867,0
1496237500967,0
1496237501067,0
1496237501167,0
1496237501267,0
1496237501367,0
1496237501467,0

2) `Foo | awk '/Value2/{printf($6)}'` prints 00000000000
3)`Foo | awk '/Value2/{printf($6)}' | awk '1'` produces nothing !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Foo | cmd` produces output but `Foo | cmd | awk '{print}'` doesn't then your problem is buffering. Google `stdbuf line buffering` (in particular see http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/) and use it like:

```
Foo | stdbuf -o0 awk '...' | awk '...'
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. Absolutely true :  everything works fine until I add the 2nd pipe. btw, `Foo | awk '1' | awk '1'`works

Comment: THANK YOU ! WAW ... you saved my life. Could you please explain why ?

Comment: You're welcome. Did you read the reference page I gave you in my answer? It explains why at great length.